# Photo print extremely dark and yellow. Profiling failed. What now?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, color-management

I was given a Canon S9000 large-format photo printer which works perfectly in Windows 7.

In Ubuntu 15.10, with the (default) Gutenprint v5.2.11-pre1 driver, prints come out extremely dark, and with a strong yellow cast.  Linux had the same problem with my previous photo printer, an HP b8850.  With the HP, I was unable to solve the problem with colour correction, but it was notorious for having bad firmware.

I tried very briefly to fix this with an ArgyllCMS icc profile on cheap inkjet paper (I happen to have a Colormunki photo), but it did not improve things at all -- [many light tints are still printed as yellow, and many dark ones are still printed as black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE3Vv.jpg).

Will I be able to fix the Canon's bad prints with a colour profile if I persevere?  I don't want to waste a bunch of time, ink, and paper trying to profile the printer if this is a fundamental driver problem.

Basically, what should I try next?  Or should I just give up and do all my colour printing from Windows?

Things tried:

- [changing to CYMK mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708702/canon-printer-color-printing-too-dark?rq=1), also CMY and RGB
- Creating a rudimentary ICC with ArgyllCMS and a ColorMunki
- [TurboPrint](http://zedonet.com/en_shop_turboprint.phtml) (seems to work, but CAD$90 to get ICC profiles is out of reach).

Comment: [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1318472/653727) to another printer question outlines the steps to get an Epson printer calibrated and profiled with argyllcms on Ubuntu 20.04. Was this the same method used?

Comment: I had a brief period of success with no calibration required by the simple expedient of using a Windows VM for a print server.  The device died a couple weeks later with some sort of "print head not found" error.  I've outsourced my printing and am much happier.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this page may help you:
[Canon printer color printing too dark](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708702/canon-printer-color-printing-too-dark)

I have a similar problem. I recently installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04. My memory is that colours on my Epson were fine. However I have been travelling and using friends' printers. With both an HP Deskjet 3050A and a Canon MG6800 (using CUPS+Gutenprint driver), the cyan and magenta were correct but the yellow was too dark and mustardy, making the red, green and blue too dark.